# Nginx rewrite / to subfolder

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx, ispconfig

I have a server with ISPConfig + Nginx + PHP, which sets the default webroot to `/{userdir}/web`. I have access to that folder only, and I cannot change the docroot in nginx.

Most frameworks use a subfolder as their docroot, for example if I install CakePHP, the docroot should be set to `/{userdir}/web/webroot`

But, because I cannot change the docroot, I need to make some rewrite rules in nginx which will basically change anything going to `/` to go into `/webroot/` I tried the default rewrite rules with CakePHP, and that works fine, because they have an `index.php` file in the project root directory, so that maps out fine. The problem is for example when trying to access `/favicon.png` because of the extension, it needs to be served as a file, but there are no rewrite rules for that. Is there some magic rewrite rule, which will route everything to a subfolder as if it were the document root?
Here are the default rewrite rules that CakePHP recommends:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#nginx

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem, were you able to fix it?

Comment: Not completely, but I have some vhost files here which get the job done: https://github.com/half2me/ispconfig-conf